# Create model with a link to static-file when created

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model

```py
class myModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)
    start_price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    image_url = models.URLFild(max_length=512,default="/static/media/wait_logo.png' %}") #Issue
```

which links to an initial image (`wait_logo.png`) when created.

The problem is that it's not very automatic, if I change my static-folder.
In the template; if I want to refer to a static image I can use

`<a href="{% static 'media/wait_logo.png' %}`

is there a way to extract the same static-path in `models.py` and use that in the default-value?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out, that we can get the static_url by

```py
from django.conf import settings

static_url = settings.STATIC_URL

class myModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE,null=True)
    start_price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    image_url = models.URLFild(max_length=512,default=static_url+"media/wait_logo.png' %}") #Fixed
```

Comment: What if STATIC_URL or image name changes? NULL with default applied on template/view level would perfectly work.

Comment: if STATIC_URL does change, that shouldn't affect it since its dynamic. If the image name changes then you can't do anything - just as you can't do anything if the image URL change

Comment: `that shouldn't affect it since its dynamic` nope, old urls are stored in the DB. Only new records will get "dynamic" new url.
`you can't do anything` - in case of solution in template/view you just change the name and that's it - all pages requiring this default image now refer new file.